# Release hokuyo_node for kinetic on PR2?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, hokuyo-node, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

the hokuyon_node page on the ROS wiki says :

"Looking for a newer driver? urg_node is fully REP-138 compliant AND compatible with Ethernet/MultiEcho Hokuyos! Hokuyo_node will remain maintained for current users and PR2s. "

It seems that all packages needed to run a PR2 under Ubuntu 16.04/ROS kinetic have been released, except for the hokuyo_node package.

Is urg_node compatible with hokuyo_node from the msgs point of vue or have all the PR2 stacks in kinetic been updated to use urg_node ?

Otherwise we'll need a ros-kinetic-hokuyo-node package please.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314128/release-hokuyo_node-for-kinetic-on-pr2-?/) by [mherrb](https://answers.ros.org/users/80/mherrb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2019-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PR2 packages for Kinetic have been updated to use urg_node ; see https://github.com/PR2/pr2_robot/pull/257 and https://github.com/PR2/pr2_robot/commit/02bc8091b8961dbf6f581d30d33c2be24d378634 .

The pr2_robot wiki page even shows that it has been released for Kinetic: http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_robot?distro=kinetic (I'm not sure if all of the other PR2 packages have been released or not)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mherrb](https://answers.ros.org/users/80/mherrb/) on 2019-01-30**:
Thank you. I just missed the need to update /etc/udev/rules.d/73-pr-aliases.rules to run urg_node instead of hokuyo_node there. But this is because I'm maintaining my own fork of the pr2-udev package.